# What is the maximum row limit for SQL Developer Import excel?

Tags: sql, oracle

Excel import in sql developer to Oracle DB is not working. Anybody have an idea such that will be there any row limit for a single time import because we have some thousands of records. Please help...

Comment: Have you tried to import a single row or just a few rows? Did that work?

Comment: SQL Developer supports Excel 97 format (.xls file extension) - in this format the maximum number of rows in the spreadscheet is 65536.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server dont have any restriction to export excel.

based on the Excel version your using , the row limit of Excel matters.

in Excel 2010 we have 1048576 row per sheet.

Excel 97 - 65536.

Answer (score 1):

In addition  I have experienced Memory issue of while importing a large Excel file.

So Please keep in mind that your server performance also play a vital role in this..